# Simple generic collection to add elements

Tags: c#, generic-collections

What collection should I use from C# that suports generic only for adding elements ?
I tried using `ArrayList`, but I see that it's a non-generic type.

Sorry if this is a duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: What use is a collection which is only "for adding elements"? What do you intend to do with this collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic generic collection is `List<T>`. It is in System.Collections.Generic namespace.

You can use it for example this way:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>() { "This", "is", "list", "of", "strings" }
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) is all the generic collections in C#

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<T>, IEnumerable<T>, ..
```

Are these the kind of things you're looking for? I don't really understand the question.

Hope this helps

Comment: IEnumerable isn't really a collection but a description of operations that can be performed on a collection.

Comment: no this helps not - don't answer if you don't understand - sorry

Answer (score 1):

You're probably after List. If you want a collection of unique elements, consider [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) instead.